# What is the difference between the twist and twistd commands?

Tags: twisted

Twisted has an old `twistd` command and a newer `twist` command. Are they equivalent except that `twistd` daemonizes itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`twistd` is the original command line runner.  It has a much larger number of features.  Daemonization is one of those features.

`twist` is a newer command line runner.  It aims to fix some of the mistakes of `twistd`.  Built-in daemonization is considered one of those mistakes but there are others.  It is also missing some features of `twistd` which are not obviously mistakes.

Comment: You might get more attention on that question if you ask it as a new question instead of as a comment here.